# how to import fontAwsome icon into sideBar-menu

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

I am working in a Vue.js project

I am using fontAwsome library

there are my versions:

```json
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
"@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.2",
```

I did this at main.js:

```js
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { faChessKnight, faChessQueen, faChessKing, faChartLine } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";

library.add(faChessKing);

Vue.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon);
```

and now I can add the icons this way:

```html
<font-awesome-icon icon="chess-king" />
```

BUT/AND

I am using vue-sidebar-menu: [`vue-sidebar-menu`](https://npm.io/package/vue-sidebar-menu) and I would like to use the fontAwsomeIcons inside the vue-sidebar-menu structure:

```js
href: '/',
title: 'Dashboard',
icon: I want to use icon from fontAwsome here
```

what is the correct syntax to use fontAwsome icons here?

PS: this is a console log of faChessKing:

```
Object { prefix: "fas", iconName: "chess-king", icon: (5) […] }​
icon: Array(5) [ 448, 512, [], … ]​​
0: 448​​
1: 512
2: Array []
​3: "f43f"
​​4: "M400 448H48a16 16 0 0 0-16 16v32a16 16 0 0 0 16 16h352a16 16 0 0 0 16-16v-32a16 16 0 0 0-16-16zm16-288H256v-48h40a8 8 0 0 0 8-8V56a8 8 0 0 0-8-8h-40V8a8 8 0 0 0-8-8h-48a8 8 0 0 0-8 8v40h-40a8 8 0 0 0-8 8v48a8 8 0 0 0 8 8h40v48H32a32 32 0 0 0-30.52 41.54L74.56 416h298.88l73.08-214.46A32 32 0 0 0 416 160z"
​​length: 5
​​<prototype>: Array []
​iconName: "chess-king"
​prefix: "fas"
​<prototype>: Object { … }
```

EDIT:
the vue.js version is `"vue": "^2.6.12"`

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're using Vue 2 or Vue 3? As the usage for this varies between the two versions.

Comment: I am editing the question. Is "vue": "^2.6.12" I am afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this out in a fresh Vue 3 project, and the following code sample should work for you. There were some slight changes between the two versions, which I guess was the issue.

First, import the icon

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faChessKing } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faChessKing)
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

Then, to use

```js
// menu
{
  href: '/',
  title: 'Dashboard',
  // Set icon as font-awesome
  icon: {
    element: 'font-awesome-icon',
    attributes: {
      // Then under icon.attributes, specify the icon to use
      icon: 'chess-king'
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to use slots for the toggle and dropdown icon, then this would correspond to:

```html
<sidebar-menu>
  <font-awesome-icon slot="toggle-icon" icon="chess-king"></font-awesome-icon>
  <font-awesome-icon slot="dropdown-icon" icon="chess-king"></font-awesome-icon>
</sidebar-menu>
```

---

If you're only using a few icons, another option would be to simply download the assets you need, from FA. This saves you having to add all those Font-Awesome dependencies for such a simple feature. E.g.

`icon: { element: 'span', class: 'my-icon', attributes: {}, text: ''}`